# pi3 GPU functionaly with camera

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3

In my project I have 2 main tasks – image recognition for the camera frames and saving the vidoes.
I think to use pi GPU here for accelerate this.
Is it possible using pi GPU get the frames from camera, than convert and save them in SD card?
And meantime pass the frames to processor for doing image recognition?

Can someone please provide some info about how I can use GPU and processor separately and what video-camera related operations can GPU do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you really just want to use the umat class. It makes a lot of opencvs functions run on the GPU (if possible). It can in some cases release a lot of cpu time for other tasks.

Some opencv functions are also often multiple times faster when run on a GPU.

See [opencv-transparent-api](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/amp/)

You can also easily find examples using it here on stack overflow.

Comment: wow amazing!! thanks much! let me read it. By the ways seems umat does not have python wrapper((

Comment: I want to use Haar image recognition